# Why does my VPN service work on my cellular network but not when I'm using residential Wifi?

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I've recently set up an OpenVPN server on my home network that should allow me to tunnel into my home network from outside my home network.

When I use my phone's cellular network and I turn on the OpenVPN client to tunnel into my home's network, everything works as expected.

For example, `192.168.0.1` directs me to my home's network router. I can SSH into all my home's devices using their local IP addresses etc. As far as I can tell, I am attached to my home network as a client, which is the expected behaviour.

However, when I was at my friend's place and I turned on my OpenVPN client on my laptop while using their home Wifi in order to access my home network, I had problems.

For example, `192.168.0.1` directed me to my friend's router. I could not SSH into any of my home's local devices using their local IPs. It was as though I wasn't attached to my home network at all. However, when I checked "what's my IP", it correctly displayed my home network's public IP, confirming that I was indeed attached to my home network.

Can someone explain what is happening and how I can fix this issue?

To be clear, I'm using the latest official OpenVPN clients on my mobile (iOS) and laptop (MacOS). I'm using the exact same OpenVPN profile on both devices. The OpenVPN Access Server is version 2.4.7 running on an Ubuntu 20.10 server.

Comment: it sounds like you and your friend have the same network defined (192.168.0.0/24) which is just fine until you join the networks with a VPN, without a technology like NAT in play. I'd recommend that if you really want to do this, configure your local network and its hosts to use a network like 192.168.249.0/24 or really anything other than .0.0, .1.0, or .254.0. those are the most commonly used internal home network addresses. routing rules work on destination address, so your addresses have to be different than the LAN addresses, so that the host or router can route your traffic onto the VPN.

Comment: Ohhh interesting. I always assumed that when using a VPN, all my traffic would immediately bypass the local router and be forwarded to my VPN server. So am I correct in understanding that when I try to connect to an IP address on my home network, my friend's router looks up the address on his network first and never forwards the traffic to my VPN server? I would've thought that since my friend's router can't find the specific IP address I'm trying to reach, it would've forwarded it along to my VPN server anyways...

Comment: yep. VPNs very by type, but OpenVPN uses your system route table, to lookup the gateway and exit interface to reach the network (or uses the default route in the case of a route-to-router scenario). so your VPN software will create a route to the remote network, where the exit interface is the VPN tunnel adapter, but traffic will only go into it if the destination address matches that route. in this case, your VPN route is overridden by the local networks default gateway, because your system can;t tell the difference between your network and your friends.

Comment: so as an example if I had a route-to-router VPN setup with a friend, and I had .xx.0/24 and they had .yy.0/24, from any LAN host on my network, I could ping .yy.10 and the traffic would be sent to my router (.xx.1), which has a routing rule that says all traffic for .yy.0/24 goes through the interface tun0, and passes from 10.0.0.1 to 10.0.0.2, and is passed on by the remote router to .yy.10. in a host-to-router scenario, all those things are true except that the localsystems route table contains a route for xx.0/24 which exits out the tun0 interface. so its all about routes.

Comment: There is also the concept of Split Tunneling, which is likely where you are getting stuck. most modern VPN clients, will allow traffic destined for the local network to go out the local network interfaces, rather than through the tunnel. without split tunneling, you would lose accessibility to all hosts on the LAN. some VPN clients will force all traffic through the VPN tunnel (like the old Cisco von client), but newer clients will only override the default gateway, leaving the routes to the LAN exposed. that causes the local LAN routes to win due to their specificity(more specific routes win)

Comment: Thank you for all the extra clarifications. I think I'm starting to understand what you're explaining now. So sorry for the slow response! I was re-reading your comments and researching online to look up foreign terms to try and understand everything. I also did some digging in OpenVPN's docs to see if there was a setting I could toggle server-side and I think I found it? I'm guessing if I turn ["Should clients be allowed to access network services on the VPN gateway IP address?"](https://tinyl.io/3TXY) to "No", then OpenVPN would act like the old Cisco von client?

Comment: Finally note that in a host-to-router/host scenario, the localhost still needs the ability to send traffic to the default gateway in order to send your tunnels traffic onto the internet via its WAN, so even if you have  a local tunnel adapter, that is completely useless unless the tunnel's traffic can be routed to the router physically present on the network. so even when the VPN is engaged, the existence of the underlying LAN is unavoidable.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don;t think that setting will fix the matter. thats really about allowing additional services (ports) on the VPN Server end, and have them be accessible to the VPN's clients. the problem you are having is that the traffic you want to send is not being sent through the VPN tunnel at all, because of the identical IP schemes.  I'm sorry, I don;t see a solution to your problem other than changing your subnet, unless you can drop a NAT between the networks, and I'm unclear on how you would do that. sorry.

Comment: I see. Thanks anyways for sharing your networking knowledge with me Frank, I really appreciate it :) This was really helpful in improving my understanding. Going to be doing more reading after this conversation haha.

Comment: @FrankThomas: Future readers might prefer to have all the comments assembled into one answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we've discussed, the issue is that when you are at your friends house, your local network (the friends) and your remote network (your LAN at home) use the same IP network (192.168.0.0/24).

A VPN [Tunnel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunneling_protocol) is not magic. At its most basic, they are formed of packets containing an encrypted payload, which is a packet that is passing through the "tunnel". The term "tunnel" can be a little misleading if you look at it from multiple layers. it is a "Tunnel" from a high-level (logical) perspective, and you just put packets into it, and they come out the other side. When you look at the lower layers though, the VPN circuit is just packets inside of packets, which are moving across the physical network.

The point I'm trying to make here is that a VPN tunnel still needs the underlying local network your endpoint is connecting from. It has to have a LAN IP, and know the [default gateway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_gateway) to use to reach other networks. This is a common confusion, due to marketing for VPN products that protect phone and laptop users while at the coffee shop. They present the connection as though it were a wormhole that you can dump traffic into that is separate from the coffee shop network, but the reality is that the encryption is what keeps you safe, not some degree of separation from the LAN. Your packets are still traversing the LAN, and exiting the shop's router onto their ISP network.

There are many kinds of [VPNs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) (including many that I don't believe fit the defintion), but we are talking about [OpenVPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenVPN), a reasonably traditional type that uses a virtual network adapter.

Systems use a construct called a [Route Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing_table), which tells the system how to reach other networks. All Internet capable machines have a Default Gateway, a special route that points to a destination of 0.0.0.0 which means all unspecified networks. That way your system doesn't need a route specifically to google.com's network, it just knows where to send all the traffic it doesn't have a more specific path to. A route consists of a Destination and Mask, a Gateway (an IP on a router on the local network that is able to reach the remote destination), the nic that the traffic should exit to reach that gateway, and generally some kind of weighted metric to help one route win over another, when there are multiple routes to a destination.

When the VPN adapter is activated and connected, the default gateway route for the system is changed to send traffic out the VPN virtual adapter (usually called tun0 for OpenVPN). That causes all traffic to unknown networks to go through the tunnel.

The Virtual Adapter still relies on the physical adapter and its routes though, so it can send traffic comprising the tunnel to the LAN gateway and on to the internet.

In your case, you have a default gateway route to 0.0.0.0 that exits via tun0, but you also have a route to 192.168.0.0/24 that exits via the physical adapter. Since there is a more "specific" route to destinations in 192.168.0.0/24, the traffic you wish to send to your home LAN, is not actually being routed into the tunnel, but instead is being routed out your physical adapter onto your friends LAN.

If you change your network to be a different, less common one, then traffic destined for your home LAN will pass into the tunnel, and come out on the other end as expected (unless you happen to be on the rare network that uses the same addressing layout). Avoid the networks (in 192.168.)

- .0.0
- .1.0
- .254.0

as these are the most common addresses you will find in home/SOHO network implementations.

There's one more facet to this I'd be remiss if I didn't point out. VPNs exist primarily for the purpose of connecting two Networks together. What you are describing is a client-to-network scenario, where a single remote device is being connected to a remote network. That has been the focus of our discussion. Another common use of VPN however, is to connect multiple Networks together that are not physically adjacent. That is a Network-to-Network scenario. You could for instance connect your network to your friends, from your router to theirs, or you could install a VPN endpoint server of some kind inside the network, and use it to route traffic to and from the other networks onto the LAN. In Network-to-Network scenarios, it is obvious that all the networks involved have a unique address space amongst them.